# Adding One more loop to cursor dynamically

Tags: sql-server, cursor

I want to loop through 5 items in SQL SERVER Stored procedure, using CURSOR

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Problem is,

Lets say I am done with the job of 1

When I am at position 2, I got a condition and did some logic, which adds one more item, but I have only 3 more items left in the loop.

How can I make the cursor to run for one more item ie. (from 5 items to 6 items)

**EDIT**

> I am describing one situation -
>
> I have to loop through 5 images
>
> For 1st image, if a logic results to = 1, we perform some operation,
>   and move to the next image.
>
> For 2nd  image, if a logic results to = 2, we add one default image,
>
> and again check the logic result , 
>                   if again logic results to = 2, we add one default image,
>
> ```
>             and again check the logic result till it become = 1, and then I need to move to 3rd image..
> ```

Comment: [Dyanmic Cursors](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189099(v=sql.105).aspx) may be the solution "The data values, order, and membership of the rows in the result set can change on each fetch", but it's usually better to give us enough information so that we can see whether a set-based solution would work better. Cursors should generally be a last resort when other solutions have failed.

Comment: in my experience this creates more problems than it helps. I would rather make a triggered process that looks into a job-table ( holding the items to be processed ) and simply takes the one to be processed next ( lifo/fifo/priority, pick one ). If any job adds one more item to that table, it will be scheduled automaticly, without tricking/hacking around in cursors. Of course, remove the done jobs from that table ( or mark them done with a flag-column )

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever - I have added one scenario of my requirement.

Comment: What do you mean by `add ... image`? Can you build your process so as just *not* to fetch the next row conditionally and thus iterate keeping the cursor at the same position?